# Can't Handle Data Set with Text in Byte-Format

Tags: stata

I am a beginner, starting to use a new .dta data set in Stata.
It has variables like `schooling` and `gender` with storage type 'byte', which implies they are integers.

However the individual entries are `"highschool"` or `"female"`. When I then try to stuff like

```
drop schooling if gender==female
```

it says `female not found`.

And when I try it this way

```
drop schooling if gender=="female"
```

it says `type mismatch`.

I'm confused as to what the actual problem is. I tried to convert the variables into strings with

```
gen state1 = string(state)
```

which only yielded a `state1` variable full of "1" entries.

Comment: Off-topic here as focused on details in Stata. Please see advice in the Help Center on off-topic questions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Do I see correctly, that such a question would be on-topic on stack overflow?

Comment: I am active there too. I won’t usually recommend questions for migration from CV to SE if they don’t match good standards there, by being self-contained in terms of data and code. MCVE is one search term.

Comment: .... to SO ... not SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because data in your variable `female` is stored as a byte, which I'm guessing takes only the value 0 or 1. When you look at the variable in the data editor, you might see `female` and `male`, but this is produced by a so-called value label which maps the byte to a string, e.g. (0 -> `male` and 1 -> `female`). So the correct way to perform your operations would be

```
drop schooling if gender==1
```

See these pages on [Value labels](http://wlm.userweb.mwn.de/Stata/wstatlab.htm) and [Data types](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/ddatatypes.pdf) in Stata

Comment: Thank you for your advice! 
This makes sense and I'll look into the links you provided.
I just want to note, that the variables stored as byte are not binary. I have, for example, a "byte-variable" for "state" that takes many different values.

Comment: That makes sense, I was just trying to emphasize that there is a difference between the actual data stored in the byte and the value label. If you want to see which value is assigned to which label you can type `label list gender`. Usually, variables that have a value label assigned to it will appear in blue in your data editor/browser.

Comment: [sorry, i saw your reply just after writing this]
I checked this for a variable that is binary (e.g. married) and there it is really the case that it's coded with 0 = "single" and 1 = "married". 

I can't quite figure out yet, how I find the underlying information about label-assignment. 

If I use "label list" as from your link, I get the information about all labels from every variable from the original data set (which was huge). 
But if I use "label list state" or "label list gender", I get a 'value label state not found'.

Comment: I guess that this means that there is no label list attached to state and gender. As shown in the link attached to my answer, you could attach a label list to your variables (e.g. `label define gender 0 "male" 1 "female"`) but as far as I'm aware you'll need to use the underlying byte in your code (see the code example in my answer)

Comment: @Joe gives helpful advice but storage as a byte is **not** the explanation here: you would get the same problem if the variables concerned were any other numeric type. It's the misreading of value labels as if they were string values that is (correctly) explained as the problem.

Comment: https://www.stata.com/manuals/u13.pdf explains a way to specify value labels in expressions (see 13.11 there). Note that `label list state` -- as Stata is telling you -- looks for a value label set named `state`; that value label name doesn't have to be identical to the name of the variable. But `describe state` will tell you the name of the value label associated with a variable if any is.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Nick!
This was a great explanation. 
By using  the "value label" instead of the "variable label" in *list label xy* I am now able to identify all the labels of any variable!

Comment: Good, but you mean `label list xy` as `list` is a quite different command.